# How to properly work with custom Views bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, custom-view

I'm extending a `View` where I display a bitmap, modified according to what I need.

I want to and most likely need to keep that bitmap in original size as a variable/object in case it gets zoomed-in so that it doesn't lose quality.

It seem to create `OutOfMemory` error when I use a lot of these custom views.

Now I am wondering how does one work with bitmaps in this case?
How is it that `ImageView` handles it without a problem?
How do they do this? And how do they preserve quality after the view gets resized dynamically?

Does anyone have any advice on this topic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you should store bitmaps in memory only for those of your views which are visible at the moment to save memory.

Also you should store a scaled down version of bitmap to save memory. 
[`BitmapFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class has special mechanism for this. Use [`inJustDecodeBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) property of `BitmapFactory.Options` class to load width and height of the image without memory allocation for the image itself. Then calculate the value for [`inSampleSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) property and use this property to load scaled down bitmap. Read [this article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) for deeper description.

These problems (and others concerning showing images) are solved in third-party libraries: [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) and others. These libs are widely used, so you can use them too. Also for example Glide supports extensions to modify images.

If you want to have an image view with zoom functionality there is the great [library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) for this. It includes pinch to zoom, panning, rotation and animation support, and allows easy extension. The view even optionally uses subsampling and tiles to support very large images.

Comment: Thank you.. this was helpful.. I was expecting something like this.. I will consider the options..